# How to monitor changes to a particular website CSS?

Tags: python, css, web, automation, bots

I wish to monitor the CSS of a few websites (these websites aren't my own) for changes and receive a notification of some sort when they do. If you could please share any experience you've had with this to point me in the right direction for how to code it I'd appreciate it greatly.

I'd like this script/app to notify a Slack group on change, which I assume will require a webhook.

Not asking for code, just any advice about particular APIs and other tools that may be of benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a modification of tschaefermedia's answer.

> 1. Crawl website for .css files, save.
> 2. Take an md5 of each file.
> 3. Then compare md5 of the new file will the old file.
> 4. If the md5 is different then the file changed.

Below is a function to take md5 of large files.

```
def md5(file_name):

    # make a md5 hash object
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()

    # open file as binary and read only
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        i = 0

        # read 4096 bytes at a time and take the md5 hash of it and add it to the hash total
        # b converts string literal to bytes
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b''):
            i += 1

            # get sum of md5 hashes
            # m.update(a); m.update(b) is equivalent to m.update(a+b)
            hash_md5.update(chunk)

        # check for correct number of iterations
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
        expected_i = int(math.ceil(float(file_size) / float(4096)))
        correct_i = i == expected_i

        # check if md5 correct
        md5_chunk_file = hash_md5.hexdigest()

    return md5_chunk_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Github in your workflow. That gives you a good idea of changes and ways to revert back to older versions.

Comment: Edited my question to be more clear. I'd like to monitor somebody else's websites. Not my own.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Crawl website for .css files, save change dates and/or filesize.

After each crawl compare information and if changes detected use slack API to notify. I haven't worked with slack that, for this part of the solution maybe someone else can give advice.